# Validating base64 image sent via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, image, image-processing, base64

I have the following image that I send its `src` to PHP using Ajax:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" name="picture" id="picture">
```

Send the image `src` using Ajax:

```
//Assign image src to a variable.
var imageSrc = document.getElementById('picture').src;

//Send Ajax request to upload.php.
$.ajax('upload.php', {
    method: "POST",
    //Data to send.
    data: {'image', imageSrc},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    //On success.
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);                                         
    },
    //On error.
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

In `upload.php`:

```
//Assign sent image src to a variable.
$image = $_POST['image'];
//Get image data.
$imageData = getimagesize($image);
$acceptedMimes = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg');
//Validate minimum dimensions.
if( $imageData[0] < 100 || $imageData[1] < 100 ){
    echo 'Image must be 100x100px at least.';
//Validate maximum dimensions.
}elseif( $imageData[0] > 800 || $imageData[1] > 800 ){
    echo 'Image must be 800x800px at most.';
//Validate mime.
}elseif( !in_array($imageData['mime'], $acceptedMimes) ){
    echo 'Invalid image');
//Everything is OK.
}else{
    // Upload the image to the server.
}
```

Will that be enough to make sure it's an image and prevent attacks?

Comment: You'll want to separate the meta data (ie `data:image/png;base64,`, I recommend `explode(',', $image)`) from the base64 encoded data then run the latter through [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.base64-decode.php). After that, your code should be ok

Comment: @Phil, I tried `$image = explode(',', $image); getimagesize( base64_decode($image[1]) );`, But I get an error `Warning</b>:  : failed to open stream: Invalid argument`

Comment: Ah, oops. You'll want to run the base64 decoded data through [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Comment: @Phil, Why is that for?

Comment: When you're dealing with data as strings, you need create image resources. Have a look [here for an example](https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506#file-imagemanipulator-php-L79)

Comment: @Phil, So I could use it to validate/save the image?

Comment: Yes, `imagecreatefromstring()` will return `false` if the string data isn't an image. If it returns a resource, you can use `imagesx()` / `imagesy()` to get the dimensions